# What would be the reading of the ammeter and voltmeter?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

I came across this question which asked about the reading of the ammeter and voltmeter. I tried to solve it and deduced that the centre and right resistors are in series while the left one is in parallel, thinking that this is an ideal case and that the resistance of the ammeter and voltmeter in an ideal case is zero and infinite respectively. The reading of the ammeter came out to be 0.54 A and that of the voltmeter came out to be 2.73 V. However when I checked the answer it mentioned that the reading of ammeter and voltmeter is 1 A and 5 V respectively. Am I going in the wrong direction or there is some conceptual error? Kindly help me as a beginner. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three resistors have one of their 2 wires connected to opposite poles of the voltage source with an inner resistor. Its a simple 3 equal parallel with one in series diagram

[image]